# Jax-RS Multipart response

Tags: jax-rs, multipart

I want to deliver a multipart response from my web application. I'd like to fullfil this requirement by using Jax-RS. Is it possible to provide a Multipart HTTP-Response with Jax-RS? Do I have to use MessageBodyWriter for this purpose and implement this on my own, or is there any class I can use for multipart responses.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) you can use `jersey-media-multipart` module to make your life easier. Follow the documentation on this topic: [Multipart](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart) section in Jersey User Guide or take a look at the available example [multipart-webapp](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/multipart-webapp).

Comment: Link to multipart section is broken. New link https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart