# Rest Service Jax-Rs - Post Multipart/data

Tags: java, web-services, rest, glassfish, jersey-2.0

I have a jax-rs REST service, using JEE 7 (deployed in glassfish 4), which has a method to process HTTP POST on the resource:

```
    import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam; 


    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadVideo(
            @FormDataParam("files") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("files") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) { 
        try {

            //do something

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return toReturn.build();
    }
```

My pom.xml in ejb is :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

And I registered the rest resource with these annotations:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {

@Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        resources.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
        return resources;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.myBean.upload");
        return properties;
    }  
}
```

When I try to start the server I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
>   org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.transaction.internal.TransactionalExceptionInterceptorProvider
>   to org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ComponentProvider

I already read this questions :[Jersey 2 injection source for multipart formdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288856/jersey-2-injection-source-for-multipart-formdata) and [How can I define a JAX-RS service that processes multi-part data in JEE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456243/how-can-i-define-a-jax-rs-service-that-processes-multi-part-data-in-jee) but I cannot find a solutions. Any suggestions?

-Log produced

> WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod]
>   org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
>   ProcessAnnotatedType, BeanManager) receives events for all
>   annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or
>   a generic type with bounds. WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method
>   [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private
>   org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
>   ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types.
>   Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type
>   with bounds. WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method
>   [BackedAnnotatedMethod]
>   org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
>   ProcessAnnotatedType, BeanManager) receives events for all
>   annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or
>   a generic type with bounds. WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method
>   [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public
>   org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
>   ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types.
>   Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type
>   with bounds. WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method
>   [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private
>   org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
>   ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types.
>   Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type
>   with bounds. WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method
>   [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public
>   org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes
>   ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types.
>   Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type
>   with bounds.

Comment: What happens if you put all the dependencies' `<scope>` as `provided`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, now the server starts but all the Rest Resource doesn't work. They all respond with 404. I don't know why (the url is the same as before)

Comment: Do you see any server logs from Jersey? The reason I said to put the scope as provided is the Glassfish already has all the Jersey jars, and (the version) may conflict with the ones you add to your project. I don't see how _not_ providing the jars would cause the app not to run, as Glassfish already has them. I don't know

Comment: Can you add some logging in the application class to see if it's being created

Comment: @peeskillet I edit the questions so you can see the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.
For the first problem :

> Cannot cast
>   org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.transaction.internal.TransactionalExceptionInterceptorProvider
>   to org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ComponentProvider

the solution was the one given by @peeskillet.

My real problem was a little different since I miss to register all the packages with Rest Resource. I post here the solution for this problem anyway:

```
        @ApplicationPath("/rest")
        public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {

        @Override
            public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
                final Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
                resources.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
                return resources;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
                Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
                String array[] = {"com. myBean.home","com. myBean.upload","com.bandyer.search","com.bandyer.mail"};
                properties.put("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", array);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is not the solution for you initial problem, but you can update your answer a little bit and accept it (probably tomorrow) to mark the question as solved.